# Regular expression - Avoiding characters

Tags: c#, regex, regex-negation

While using some regex in C#, I'm facing the following problem :

Consider this simple string : **~0~This is a simple text~POP~NIZ~0~0~**

I would like to pick any strings between two '~', that contains more than 3 chars except of course the '~'. In my example, the would be :

This is a simple text

I could make something like : ([\w]|[\d]|.|\,.................){4-500}

I would end with a really long regex, impossible to debug and not readable...

Instead, I would prefer to create a regex like **"Give me any characters, except '~' that is contained between '~' and '~' "**.

I can't find a way to use [^] properly !

How can I do this ?

Thanks in advance !

**ANSWER : I've finally done this : ~[^~]{3,}~**

**It takes everything but '~', contained between two '~' and that is more than three chars long.**

Thanks for your answers !

Comment: `~[^~]{3,}~` may be wrong - what about `~1234~acbd~`? Do you need both matches?

Comment: You're right, but I completed my regex to avoid those numbers ! But for the example purpose, yes I don't mind those numbers ! Thanks for your comment !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't mind a possible extra batch from the start and the end, it should be as easy as:

```
[^~]{3,}
```

Or, you can just split and take the long ones:

```
var tokens = str.Split('~').Where(s => s.Length >= 3);
```

If you do want to limit the characters to a specific set, you can use lookahead and behind to make sure. This will not consume the tilde signs, so you get two matches for `~123~abc~` (again, you can use `[^~]` if you are move comfortable with it):

```
(?<=~)[\w\d\s]{3,}(?=~)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex `(?:~([^~]{3,})~)`
It will match everithing between two ~~ (wont catch ~)

Comment: Wrapping the whole match in `(?: )` does very little - it is semantically the same as nothing at all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Kobi is right, yours works but the (?: ) seems useless ? For what purpose did you put that ?

Comment: If i eliminate the ?: il will capture 2 blocks  `   1. ~123~ and  2. 123 ` So i put ?: and make the first block 'non-capturable'

Comment: Either way you should get a `Match` with `Value=~123~`, and `Groups[1].Value = 123`. `Groups[0]` is the whole match in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
~([^~]{3}[^~]+)~
```

(tested)